# R can't find MATLAB Runtime

Tags: r, matlab, cmd

I made an R script that generates a command line that's supposed to launch a MATLAB ".exe" file with parameters.

The generated command line looks like this:

```
cmd = "X:\matlabscript.exe [xxx,xxx,...]"
```

Then I enter the command in the shell:

```
shell(cmd)
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find version 9.7 of the MATLAB Runtime. 
Attempting to load mclmcrrt9_7.dll.
Please install the correct version of the MATLAB Runtime.
Contact your vendor if you do not have an installer for the MATLAB Runtime.
Warning message:
In shell(cmd) :
  l'exécution de 'X:\matlabscript.exe [xxx,xxx,...]' a échoué avec le code d'erreur 65535
```

When I copy-paste the command in CMD.exe it works fine.

I also added the runtime path in the system environment variables "path" but it didn't change anything.

How can I launch the MATLAB Runtime via R?

Comment: Do you have Matlab installed on the machine? Does changing the order of the paths in the system env variables fix it? See [this](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/dotnet/install-the-matlab-runtime.html#bvf5_vk-5) page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

I had to restart the computer as restarting only the R session wasn't enough.

It's working fine now !